# Linear algebra sequence

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me with this assignment, thanks so much.
The 2 questions are actually linked!

> 1. Explain what the following exact sequences tell us about the linear transformation $T:V\to W$
>        a) $0\to V\xrightarrow{T} W$
>        b) $V\xrightarrow{T}W\to 0$
>        c) $0\to V\xrightarrow{T}W\to 0$
>    where $0$ means the 0-dimensional vector space and the linear transformation $0\to V$ and $W\to 0$ are not labelled but are defined uniquely.
> 2. Suppose there is an exact sequence
>    $$0\xrightarrow{T_0}\mathbb{R}^{k_1}\xrightarrow{T_1}\mathbb{R}^{k_2}\xrightarrow{T_2}\cdots\xrightarrow{T_{n-1}}\mathbb{R}^{k_n} \xrightarrow{T_n}0$$
>    Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i k_i=0$.

Answer (score 1):

1. This should follow immediately from definitions--just try it!
2. Hint: Consider the case $n=3$

$$0\to V\to W\to U\to 0$$

Then, this is saying $\dim V-\dim W+\dim U=0$, or $\dim W-\dim V=\dim U$, or $W/V=U$ which is true because the first isomorphism theorem says

$$U\cong W/\ker (W\to U)=W/\text{im}(V\to W)$$

Comment: so for the proving in q2, can I just assume the case for n as what you have done as my proof?

Answer (score 1):

The exact sequence notation says that the kernel of one of the maps is the image of the preceding map. So

1a) Image(map 1) = 0, so ker(T)=0. That is, T is 1-1.

1b) ker(map 2) = W, so Im(T) = W. That is, T is onto.

1c) a and b both hold here, implying T is an isomorphism.

Comment: okay thanks for the answer!